# How to prevent macOS or Finder from popping up the dialogue to restore my iPhone in recovery mode?

Tags: iphone, finder, jailbreak, dialog

macOS 11.7.

Every time when my connected iPhone enters recovery mode, Finder automatically opens a new window and shows this dialogue. Not sure how possible it is, but I'd like it not to show up automatically, without affecting USB communications with this iPhone.

[image: Prompt to restore iPhone]

Answer (score 0):

You can just quit finder before plugging in the device. That is only an option if you don't need finder for whatever you want to do with the iphone.
You don't need finder to be open to access the device through the terminal or other apps